# Why doesn't Clockworkmod let me restore my backups on my Sprint Galaxy Note 2?

Tags: backup, clockworkmod-recovery, restore, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I made a backup with Clockworkmod and now when I go to restore it it just says no files found.  I have tried moving the backup into different folders on the SDcard like `sdcard/0` and `sdcard/0/0` and it still can't find the files.

Comment: Are you storing the backup on the internal SDcard and then factory resetting and then trying to restore from that backup?

Comment: see my answer then.

Answer (score 1):

CWM stores its backups in special folders below `<sdcard>/clockworkmod/backup`. Folder names reflect the times the corresponding backups where created, e.g. `2013-02-01.00.28.49`. In those directories you should find the [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) images. If you place yours there, CWM should find them.

Alternatively, you can also use apps like [Nandroid Manager * ROOT](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.h3r3t1c.bkrestore) or [AppExtractor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handyandy.appextractor) to restore individual apps/data from your Nandroid backups.

Note that when you've used TWRP to create those backups, this uses different locations, as you can see in the screenshots of *Nandroid Manager*.

Comment: So will Nandroid Manager let me restore app data from a clockworkmod backup?

Comment: That's what its description says. By the way, *Titanium Backup* does that as well. CWM/TWRP themselves only let you restore "all or nothing", but these apps are explicitly designed for selective restores.

Comment: That is helpful, but I would still like to know why clockworkmod can't find the backup or to know if there is a different way to restore it.

Comment: Have you tried placing your `*.img` files in the directory structure described in my answer? For example, into `/sdcard/clockworkmod/backup/2013-02-01.00.28.49`? Maybe you could [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/48188/edit) your question and add some more details: which files do you have (just in case), what is the root of your sdcard (e.g. `/sdcard` -- but it looks like in your case rather `/sdcard/0` has to be implied; make sure you're logged in with the primary user then when copying the image files)?

Answer (score 0):

When you are performing a full factory reset, it wipes most of your internal storage, and most likely it is also wiping the backups that you are creating. If you want to restore from a backup, make sure that you create that backup somewhere on the externalSD or move the file over to your computer before you perform a factory reset.

This is why you can never find the backup after factory resetting. You are essentially deleting it right after you create it.

Comment: I can find the backup on my phone after factory resetting and I have also tried to put it on an external sd card so it is not being deleted but when I click restore in clockworkmod it just says "no files found"

Comment: Okay, I use TWRP as my recovery, but I am sure it is similar. Make sure you are placing the backup in a specific backup folder for CWM located on the externalSD. Create the backup and then go and check that it is there before you factory reset. Do you have some sort of a file manager installed?

Comment: Yes I have done that, I have put the backup in what should be the correct location(s). Is there any other reason why clockworkmod wouldn't be able to find it?

Comment: Like I said, I don't typically use CWM, but instead use TWRP, so little details like this I am not able to totally solve. You could try to make the backup using [Online Nandroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.h3r3t1c.onnandbup&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5oM3IzdDFjLm9ubmFuZGJ1cCJd) to perform the backup and maybe you will get a different result.

Comment: I have switched to TWRP to but since I made this backup when I was using clockworkmod I believe that you can only restore it through clockworkmod.  Is there another process that I could use to restore a clockworkmod backup.

Comment: OHHHH, so you made this backup awhile ago and are still looking for it? Then I might have to inform you that your data is lost. Next time make sure that you can find the back up before you fully wipe the device.

Comment: I have the backup. I CAN SEE THE FILES, but clockworkmod does seem to be finding it even when I move the files into what should be the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is too late but I will post it for future refence for those who end up here and encounter the same problem like I just did. After wiping everything and putting the backup back on the SD, I had to reboot the phone in order fo CWM to recocnize the backup. When I had put the back up into the SD from the PC while in CWM, It wouldn't recocnize the backup and the same error msg popped up.

Answer (score 0):

i had similar problem and on reaching here i followed up on the discussion and i was able to make the CWM see the backup by making sure the file structure was in place

sdcard/

-------- clockworkmod

------------------ backup

-------------------------- 2013-02-01.00.28.49

----------------------------------------- * list of backup files *

ending up having something like this  ..

sdcard/clockworkmod/backup/2013-02-01.00.28.49/

the mistake i was making was that i refused to include the last part of the file structure i copied the files inside to the backup directly so doing the cwm refused to see the files since the folder structure is not complete 
and on adding the last folder to it which is the 2013-02-01.00.28.49 (note : yours 
can be different based on the time the backup was made

... And it worked

---